# I want to pass a variable in xpath using @findBy annotation for webelement in java

Tags: java, selenium

I have a class which has annotations `@FindBy` for defining `WebElement`. I need to pass the env variable in annotation.

```
String environment = System.getProperty("env");

@FindBy(id ="com.verizon.pilot.vzcv:id/circuitId")


WebElement textBox; 

// I need pilot to have variable as environment which has different text.
```

I am using this `WebElement` in other methods.

```
public void openCktByOntSno(String key) throws Exception {                 
    if (textBox.isDisplayed()) {                        
        textBox.click();
```

I know we need to give only constants in @FindBy, looking for alternate solutions here.

Comment: The thing is that annotation values have to be known in compile time - hence you can't use variables there (since variables get a value only in runtime). If this solution is a must, start googling `java reflection` (self modifying code is always great `fun`.)

Comment: I have only 3 variables to add. following is alternate solution i can use, but it takes double the time.
@FindAll({
 @FindBy(id ="com.verizon.pilot.vzcv:id/circuitId"),
        @FindBy(id ="com.verizon.sit.vzcv:id/circuitId"),
 @FindBy(id ="com.verizon.sit1.vzcv:id/circuitId")  })
 WebElement textBox;

Comment: I think your own suggested solution is probably the best.  If all three locators could be reduced to an array list, that would have been my suggestion, but it looks like there is no id or partial id that would work except maybe using an xpath where `//*[ends-with(@resource-id,'id:circuitid')]`

Comment: Thanks bill, I am using AndroidDriver for tablet apps, and that's not recognizing this xpath.